# Return Values from a callback SQL function in node.js

Tags: sql, node.js, functional-programming

Currently I'm working on a node.js application, with a register function. For this function I need to check a username is already taken or not. Unfortunately the SQL module in node just accepts a callback function from which I cannot send any booleans back.

Here is some code from my controller module:

```
async function createUser(req, res) {

        try {
            const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(); //standard ist 10
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
            const newUser = {
                userName: req.body.username,
                userPassword: hashedPassword
            };
            const userExists = model.checkIfUserExists(newUser.userName);
    
            if (userExists == false){
    
                // create new user
    
            } else {
    
                // Send json back "user already exists
    
            }
            res.status(201).json(newUser);
    
        } catch {
            res.status(500);
        }
    
    }
```

And here is the code of the model:

```
function checkIfUserExists(Username){
    console.log("Checking if user exists");
    let sql = "select * from users where user_name = ?";

    db_conn.query(sql, Username, (err, result) => {

        if (err){
            throw  err;
        }
        console.log(result);

        if (result.length > 0){

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }


    });

}
```

Unfortunately the "checkIfUserExists" method never returns back a true or false which leads to the "userExists " variable to be null.

I'd like to know how to do return the bollean there or how to solve the problem in a more elegant way.

Please help me to fix this code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass a callback to `checkIfUserExists` or use promises. If I were you, and since you are already using async/await, I would make your return of `checkIfUserExists` be a promise. So...your code could become

```
function checkIfUserExists(Username) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        console.log("Checking if user exists");
        let sql = "select * from users where user_name = ?";

        db_conn.query(sql, Username, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log(result);
            if (result.length > 0) {
                resolve()
            } else {
                reject()
            }
        });
    })
}
```

Then, your code that calls this function would be:

```
async function createUser(req, res) {
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(); //standard ist 10
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const newUser = {
            userName: req.body.username,
            userPassword: hashedPassword
        };
        await model.checkIfUserExists(newUser.userName).catch(() => {
            // Send json back "user already exists
        });
        // create user
        res.status(201).json(newUser);
    } catch {
        res.status(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you throwing err in mysql query callback, do you think that will be handled by catch statement? Try once

Comment: i just copied the users code; it can absolutely be optimized for better error handling..but that wasnt the issue. the issue was asynchronous handling. also... a `throw` will be caught just as much as a reject w/ `async/await`

Answer (score 1):

First check your catch statement and also add `await` before `model.checkIfUserExists(newUser.userName)`

```
async function createUser(req, res) {

    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(); //standard ist 10
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const newUser = {
            userName: req.body.username,
            userPassword: hashedPassword
        };
        const userExists = await model.checkIfUserExists(newUser.userName);

        if (userExists == false){

            // create new user

        } else {

            // Send json back "user already exists

        }
        res.status(201).json(newUser);

    } catch(ex) {
        res.status(500);
    }

}
```

return promise from this function:

```
function checkIfUserExists(Username){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Checking if user exists");
    let sql = "select * from users where user_name = ?";

    db_conn.query(sql, Username, (err, result) => {

        if (err){
            return reject(err);
        }
        console.log(result);

        if (result.length > 0){

            return resolve(true);
        } else {

            return resolve(false);
        }


    });
  })
}
```